# Reference request on a topic on hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry

I would like to know some information on the induced  geometry of $n$-dimensional  Hyperbolic space as a hyper-plane of $n+1$-dimensional Euclidean space given by $x^2_{n+1} -x^2_n-...-x^2_1=1$. I would be grateful if you introduce me a book with this approach.

Comment: Do you really mean a hyperplane, and not the hyperboloid $x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2-\dots-x_1^2=1$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry. I had a typo. you'r right. I corrected it.

Comment: *Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds*, by John Ratcliffe, is a very good and very complete reference.